# Bitnami Springcloud dataflow deployment error in kubernetes using external mysql database

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am deploying spring cloud dataflow stream from artifacthub.io using bitnami chart.
I am facing issye with JDBC driver and flyway error during pod startup in the latest chart but is working fine in old chart.
I want to deploy latest version of spring cloud dataflow using external Mysql Database.

I am trying to install spring cloud dataflow through bitnami chart.
Application version: 2.10.3
Chart version: 20.0.0
Using external Mysql Database

I am getting an error related to Mysql Driver and Flyway. But in version 2.9.1 it works fine with the same configuration.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://host:3306/skipper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql://host:3306/skipper
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:331) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:114) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error with skipper server when i upgrade version 2.8 to 2.9 and with dataflow server 2.9 to 2.10.
And i resolved the problem with changing jdbcUrl.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error with skipper server when i upgrade version 2.8 to 2.9 and with dataflow server 2.9 to 2.10.
And i resolved the problem with changing jdbcUrl.
It works for me.
I use `driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`
and changes url.

before

```
jdbc:mysql://host:3306/skipper
```

after

```
jdbc:mysql://host:3306/skipper?permitMysqlScheme
```

I hope this solution also works to you.
I refer this.
[SpringBoot app can't connect to MariDB when connector version changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775617/springboot-app-cant-connect-to-maridb-when-connector-version-changed)